# Can't add WMS layer to R Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, wms, r-leaflet

I want to make a leaflet map in R with this wms servic : https://data.geopf.fr/wms-r/wms?VERSION=1.3.0
It works well in QGIS but not with addWMSTiles.

```
library(leaflet)

layer="ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST"
url="https://data.geopf.fr/wms-r/wms?VERSION=1.3.0"

leaflet() %>% 
    setView(lng=3.18766,lat = 50.46302,zoom = 12) %>%
    addWMSTiles(
      baseUrl = url,
      layers = layer,
      group = "Limites administratives",
      options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE,opacity=0.9,crs = 4326),
      attribution = "IGN"
    )
```

I try leaflet.extras2 pakcage, i try to put the number of the layer like on [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412292/cant-add-wms-layer-to-r-leaflet) but it doesnt work at all. I try to change base url...
I look trough informations in qgis with no sucess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
I have to specify the version of the service in `WMSTileOptions`, which is weird because it's the same version as the older service...

```
library(leaflet)

layer="ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST"
url="https://data.geopf.fr/wms-r/wms?VERSION=1.3.0"

leaflet() %>% 
    setView(lng=3.18766,lat = 50.46302,zoom = 12) %>%
    addWMSTiles(
      baseUrl = url,
      layers = layer,
      group = "Limites administratives",
      options = WMSTileOptions(
          format = "image/png",
          transparent = TRUE,
          opacity=0.9,
          crs = 4326,
          version="1.3.0"
        ),
      attribution = "IGN"
    )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).